# how to avoid text wrap in huxtable?

Tags: r

Consider this simple example

```
library(huxtable)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

tibble(text = c('this is a very long string my friend, quite impressive!',
                'and this is even worse !!!!! I cannot believe it LOL'),
       value = c(1,2)) %>% 
  as_hux()
```

which gives:

[image]

As you can see the text has been wrapped and the first sentence takes two rows... I would like to avoid that and just have one row per sentence (no wrap that is)

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually the text wrap takes place based on the size of your console window. If you make it big enough the line is printed in the same line. Besides that there is also `wrap` and `set_wrap` function which might help you to adjust the property.

Comment: yes but I was not able to make them work, despite extending my console window to the max..

Comment: `?print_screen` may help, also see `?options` for `"width"`